# WinForms Designer Exception

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

A WinForms form that includes a UserControl throws an exception when I attempt to display it in design mode, but runs properly when the program is ran or debugged.

The designer says:

> **The variable 'fpInfoA' is either undeclared or was never assigned.**
>   ResearchTool fMain.Designer.cs Line:282 Column:1
>   Call Stack
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)

However, it looks like the variable is assigned as I would expect in `InitializeComponent`

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // ... (Order of statements is same as in actual code) ...
    this.tpFpA = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
    this.fpInfoA = new ResearchTool.FPInfo();
    // ...
    this.tpFpA.Controls.Add(this.fpInfoA); // THIS LINE BLOWS UP IN DESIGN MODE
}
```

Thoughts on how to track down this issue?  For example, is there a way to debug initialization of the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the information on how to trace design time code execution at:

[What information do you need to fix a problem, which occurs with your products at design time?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A948.aspx)

Comment: That link seems to deal with debugging a crashed instance of VS.  In my case VS is not crashing, it's just showing an error message instead of the design view.

Comment: you will catch the exception if you follow the instructions from this link.  I think that this is what you need.  You will be able to set a breakpoint and debug your code.  Try this, I used this technique multiple times and it works.

Comment: Yep that did it.  The user control's initialization code was throwing an Exception in design mode, and that Exception was not being reported by VS.

Answer (score 7):

One workaround in case you can't fix the issue, would be to surround the offending bits of code with checks for `DesignMode`.

As in:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    if(!DesignMode)
    {
        this.fpInfoA = new ResearchTool.FPInfo();
    }
    ...
}
```

This can also speed it up a little bit if it's doing things that aren't needed in design mode and that are quite slow, like connecting to databases or similar.

Comment: The trouble is not in InitializeComponent, it's that the designer later things that this.fpInfoA was not initialized.  I'll update the question to be clear on that.

Comment: @Eric You can use the `if(!DesignMode)` anywhere in the `Form` so you can surround any code that gets called when you view the `Form` in the designer. Assuming that you don't actually need that code while in the designer of course. So I don't think your comment affect my answer unless I misunderstand.

Comment: I'm not trying to remove any code at all from design time.  As far as I can see, all of the code _should_ run in the designer.  The problem seems to be that fpInfoA is "magically" not assigned in design mode, even though there's clearly an assignment earlier in `InitializeComponents`.

Answer (score 2):

[As Hans Olsson said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082307/975724), this potentially could be resolved by checking for design-mode and disabling offending logic.

This error will also trigger if there is any issue with the constructor of your `UserControl`.  If there is an exception caused when the designer instantiates your `UserControl`, the designer will fail.  In my case, the failure resulted in the same *"[...] is either undeclared or was never assigned"* error.

For example, see the following user control:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl {

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        throw new Exception(); //Causes a designer error.
    }
}
```

Now, when observing the designer for a form that contains this `MyUserControl`, we will see something similar to the following:

[image: Winforms Designer Error]

I cannot say if the designer is like this for previous versions of Visual Studio; but as for Visual Studio 2017, you can clearly see what happened.

The designer failed because a `System.Exception` was thrown.  As a result, the variable `[REDACTED]` was thought to be undeclared or never assigned when in fact the auto-generated designer code was correct.  The issue was with the `MyUserControl`'s constructor.

Now, if you need to put logic that depends on external services/resources inside the control's constructor, you need to indicate that it should only occur during runtime.  Alternatively, you can provide mock-up resources for design-time.

To do this, you can [use the `LicenseManager` and check its current `UsageMode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/282277/975724).
The modified code below only throws the exception in runtime now, and the designer doesn't have the error anymore.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl {

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
        {
            throw new Exception(); //No longer fails in design-time.
        }
    }
}
```