# Is there a DesignMode property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

In Winforms you can say

```
if ( DesignMode )
{
  // Do something that only happens on Design mode
}
```

is there something like this in WPF?

Comment: Note that GetIsInDesignMode suffers from [the same enormous bug as the DesignMode property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664/designmode-with-controls)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

**Indeed there is**:

**[System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx)**

Example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            // Design-mode specific functionality
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I applied your solution in my application but it doesn't work. I asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987439/init-grid-row-height-doesnt-work. If you would, please join us and discuss.

Comment: @serhio Thanks for pointing that out. Are you aware of any workaround? Btw it seems that it doesn't work in Silverlight either: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/371837/designerproperties-getisindesignmode-doesnt-work-with-silverlight-pages

Comment: In VS2019 switch `Enable project code` must be enabled (or Menu->Design-> Run Project Code).

Answer (score 48):

In some cases I need to know, whether a call to my non-UI class is initiated by the designer (like if I create a DataContext class from XAML). Then the approach [from this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546934.aspx) is helpful:

```
// Check for design mode. 
if ((bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue)) 
{
    //in Design mode
}
```

Comment: I applied your solution in my application but it doesn't work. I asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987439/init-grid-row-height-doesnt-work. If you would, please join us and discuss.

Answer (score 23):

For any WPF Controls **hosted in WinForms**, `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)` does not work.

So, I created [a bug in Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/620001/system-componentmodel-designerproperties-getisindesignmode-does-not-work-if-the-wpf-is-hosted-on-a-winform#tabs) and added a workaround:

```
public static bool IsInDesignMode()
{
    if ( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Contains( "VisualStudio" ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `GetEntryAssembly()` instead of `GetExecutingAssembly()`? The latter should be returning the assembly where this property is defined

Answer (score 10):

Late answer, I know - but for anyone else who wants to use this in a `DataTrigger`, or anywhere in XAML in general:

```xml
xmlns:componentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=PresentationFramework"

<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                 Path=(componentModel:DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode)}" 
                 Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this one:

```
if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
{
    //design only code here
}
```

(Async and File operations wont work here)

Also, to instantiate a design-time object in XAML (d is the special designer namespace)

```
<Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MyViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
...
</Grid>
```

Comment: That class (`Windows.ApplicationModel`) is for Store apps, included in the Windows Runtime API. This is not an out-of-the-box WPF solution if you're just working on a regular Windows desktop application.