# WPF error adding user control

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio

The error happens when i included my own usercontrol in this line (drag & drop):

`<my:ItemParte x:Name="UcItemParte" Panel.ZIndex="6" />`

and the error says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

And I don´t know why... any help?

UPDATE:
This is the Sub New()

Shared Sub New()
        ListViewFontSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListViewFontSize", _
            GetType(Double), GetType(ItemParte))
    End Sub

```
Public Sub New()
    Try
        mModeloItem = Modelo_Item.Instance
        mModeloParte = Modelo_Parte.Instance
        mModeloParteLinea = Modelo_Parte_Linea.Instance

        ' Llamada necesaria para el Diseñador de Windows Forms.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Agregue cualquier inicialización después de la llamada a InitializeComponent().
        If Not IsInDesignMode Then
            mTextos = Textos.Instance
            mConfig = Config.Instance

            MainWin = My.Application.MainWindow

            AddHandler MainWin.VentanaMensaje.ButtonAceptarExec, AddressOf VentanaMensaje_AceptarClickCallback

            AddHandler MainWin.Fuentes.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Fuentes_PropertyChanged

            MainWin.Fuentes.RecargarFontSize()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        My.Log.WriteEntry(ex.Message, TraceEventType.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace for the error?

Comment: @Chris It´s an Visual Studio 2010 Express 
@Steve where can i get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution
http://www.forkcan.com/viewcode/186/-IsInDesignMode-for-WPF-and-Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

The error might be that you have something doing inside your `Load` event of the user control - this event fires even when form is loaded for use by designer, not only in runtime.

If that's the case, than in your Load method add

```
if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode)
{
  // ...your code
}
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425760/is-there-a-designmode-property-in-wpf)

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i don´t have any code on the load event

Comment: Do you have any code inside the constructor for your ItemParte control?

Comment: Shared Sub New()
        ListViewFontSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListViewFontSize", _
            GetType(Double), GetType(ItemParte))
    End Sub

Comment: and also
Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
            If Not IsInDesignMode Then
                mTextos = Textos.Instance
                mConfig = Config.Instance

                MainWin = My.Application.MainWindow

                AddHandler MainWin.VentanaMensaje.ButtonAceptarExec, AddressOf VentanaMensaje_AceptarClickCallback

                AddHandler MainWin.Fuentes.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Fuentes_PropertyChanged

                MainWin.Fuentes.RecargarFontSize()

            End If

    End Sub