# Can you call a class' method when you declare the object?

Tags: c#, wpf, constructor, definition

I have a class, where I declare it, but that class gets added as an item to another bigger class. Is there a way to call the `Init()` method in the same statement as the call? Similar to defining public properties/variables when you call the constructor. I don't want to call the `Init()` method in the constructor because it messes with the WPF Designer.

```
 FitsView fv = new FitsView();
 fv.Init();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a static function to do that:

```
public static FitsView CreateFitsView()
{
    var fv = new FitsView();
    fv.Init();
    return fv;
}
```

Then you simply call that static function instead of `new FitsView()`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try hooking a custom event to your FitsView if it knows when it's ready to be initialized?

And use it like this:

```
FitsView fv = new FitsView();
fv.someCustomEvent += (o,e) => { fv.Init(); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the [`StringBuilder.Append`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append.aspx) you could alter Init to return a reference to the object.

```
Public FitsView Init()
{
    //Do stuff

    return this;
}
```

Then:

```
FitsView fv = new FitsView().Init();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the designer gets problematic because of your init method there are two reasons I can think of:

- It is because something you do in `Init` method needs locality of your application (reading resources or files or using hardware)
- Calling your `Init` method needs some external assemblies to be loaded dynamically.

For the first matter you may want to check:

1. For your class: [Is there a DesignMode property in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425760/is-there-a-designmode-property-in-wpf)
2. For your view model: http://blog.laranjee.com/how-to-get-design-mode-property-in-wpf/

Also people in here pointed out this bug so please beware (hosting wpf in winforms): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/620001/system-componentmodel-designerproperties-getisindesignmode-does-not-work-if-the-wpf-is-hosted-on-a-winform#tabs

For the second matter you can wrap your `Init` method in another let's say `InitWrapper` and do your design mode check for wrapper method.