# Disable design mode for particular control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm working with a native windows control at the moment, it appears in my WPF design view as it should, but when I close the design tab it will crash the whole IDE.

Is there anyway do either of the following?..

- Stop instances of this particular class from appearing in design view.
- Have this class show an alternative image in the design view.
- Stop this native control from crashing the IDE (only on tab close).

My particular native control is [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org), I'm displaying with [HwndHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert a check for design mode,
and perform the code which causes problems only when you are not in design mode.

see:

[Is there a DesignMode property in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425760/is-there-a-designmode-property-in-wpf)

Comment: One easy way to check if you are in design mode is to check whenever application runs or not by setting some static flag in the `App.Main` (first function you get control in, no idea which one is in WPF). Designer will run your code without running `App.Main`.

Comment: @Sinatr , Why not use the framework's flag for it? (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) ,it seems simple enough to me...

Comment: I agree, better to use the framework flag, no point making a new one.

Comment: please note that there is a problem using this test when WPF control is hosted in winforms

Comment: @Gerve, if this answer indeed helped, would appreciate your upvote. thanks