# Setting "IsChecked" property only at design-time

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, design-time

I would like something similar to:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d"/>

    <ToggleButton d:IsChecked="true"/> <!-- Only at design time! -->

</UserControl>
```

But this won't work. Is there another way? I'm using Expression Blend 4.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425760/is-there-a-designmode-property-in-wpf I don't think there's a good way to do it without getting into the code behind unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try a default value?

Comment: I guess that use different view model for designer is way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind that property to your designtime's view-model's property.

Comment: My viewmodel doesn't have a property for that.