# Viewmodel is created even though IsDesignTimeCreatable=False

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, datacontext

I want to prevent the ViewModel from beeing created at Designtime.

So, the header looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="app.reports.sta"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:viewmod.reports.sta;assembly=viewmodAss"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d"              
             d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1200"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:staViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"             
             Language="de-DE">
```

The DataContext is set as shown below:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:staViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<!--With this part active, the designer throws an error from the viewmodel constructor -->
<!--Without this part, the designer works, but when the app is run, not data is displayed (which is quite obivous) -->
```

How can I set the `DataContext` so that the ViewModel won't be created at DesignTime?

Comment: simple - don't use `<UserControl.DataContext><vm:staViewModel/></UserControl.DataContext>`. it creates more problems than it is worth

Comment: but then no data is shown. What is the preferred way to set the `DataContext`?

Comment: @Mister832: Try to detect whether you're in design mode and then return as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425760/is-there-a-designmode-property-in-wpf).

Comment: @Mister832 I created a sample with the UI code you gave, the data can be displayed successfully, can you give the some code of Viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVVM, the DataContext should be set externally, i.e. you have a *MainViewModel* with some hierarchy and your control gets the DataContext through **DataBinding**. In *App.xaml.cs* (override OnStartup) you set the DataContext of your *MainWindow* to your *MainViewModel* and then show your MainWindow. Keep in mind to clear the *StartupUri* in your *App.xaml*.