# Set DesignMode for my application

Tags: .net, wpf, designmode

I have application where i can change XAML file. For example: Move and resize controls.

Inside controls we have some complex code and use next check:

```
DesigerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)
```

But this check is always false. How to set for application grid, page that we inside design mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DesignMode isn't really designed to be set. It *should* be true when the application isn't running, and it's just the XAML being rendered, for instance in Visual Studio.

However, there have been bugs with it in Visual Studio anyway, so I don't think you'll have luck getting it working in another application.

The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664/designmode-with-controls) provide a wide variety of ways of working independently of Design Mode, and you may find some of them more helpful.

Comment: Those problems with design mode appears in winforms or in WPF also?

Comment: But this is strange because my application in this case works like wpf designer and why i cannot set for controls design mode?