# GMap.NET - placing GMapControl in UserControl and then UserControl on Form yields MissingMethodException

Tags: winforms, gmap.net

I am trying to build a USerControl that contains a GMapControl. When I place the GMapControl directly on the Form, then it works as expected. If I however place the GMapControl on a UserControl, and then add that UserControl to the Form, I get errors.

For example:

My UserControl, Map.cs:

```
public Map()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
            gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(54.6961334816182, 25.2985095977783);
            gMapControl1.MinZoom = 1;
            gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 24;
            gMapControl1.Zoom = 9;

            top = new GMapOverlay("1");
            objects = new GMapOverlay("objects");
            routes = new GMapOverlay("routes");
            polygons = new GMapOverlay("polygons");

            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(routes);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(polygons);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(objects);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(top);

            gMapControl1.OnMarkerClick += new MarkerClick(gMapControl1_OnMarkerClick);
            gMapControl1.OnPolygonClick += new PolygonClick(gMapControl1_OnPolygonClick);
        }
```

Then I add this UserControl to my Form by dragging it on there. Then I get an Exception:

> Failed to create component 'Map'. The error message follows:
>   'System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
>   GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl.set_MapProvider(GMap.NET,
>   MapProviders.GMapProvider)'.    at OpenStreetMapTest.Map..ctor()'

If I have the same code that I have in the UserControl Map inside a Form, then no errors. Also, the set_MapProvider exists and works if I don't put the GMapControl inside a UserControl.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompile the code and see what the Map construtor is doing. Maybe it's locating some method by reflection. Can't think why else you'd get a `MissingMethodException` dependong on where the control is sitting.

On `DesignMode` suggestion, that property just flat out doesn't work for nested user controls which is really frustrating. However, you can use the following work around (this property would be in a `UserControlBase` class from which you would inherit)

Simply check `IsDesignerHosted` instead of `IsDesignMode`.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if the code is being run in the context of the designer
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <see cref="Component.DesignMode"/> always returns false for nested controls. This is one
        /// of the suggested work arounds here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664/designmode-with-controls
        /// </remarks>
        public bool IsDesignerHosted
        {
            get
            {
                Control ctrl = this;

                while (ctrl != null)
                {
                    if ((ctrl.Site != null) && ctrl.Site.DesignMode)
                        return true;
                    ctrl = ctrl.Parent;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thx, that worked a lot better! I was playing around a bit with different ways to check "isDesignMode", but the only one that worked was your solution  =)

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap everything inside the if ( !DesignMode )

eg.

```
Map()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if ( !DesignMode )
    {
        gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
        gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(54.6961334816182, 25.2985095977783);
        gMapControl1.MinZoom = 1;
        gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 24;
        gMapControl1.Zoom = 9;

        top = new GMapOverlay("1");
        objects = new GMapOverlay("objects");
        routes = new GMapOverlay("routes");
        polygons = new GMapOverlay("polygons");

        gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(routes);
        gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(polygons);
        gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(objects);
        gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(top);

        gMapControl1.OnMarkerClick += new MarkerClick(gMapControl1_OnMarkerClick);
        gMapControl1.OnPolygonClick += new PolygonClick(gMapControl1_OnPolygonClick);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Another issue of the DesignMode property is that it doesn't work inside the constructor of a UserControl or Form!" http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.se/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html ...