# Adding inherited form cannot find an IRRELEVANT .exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, ide, windows-forms-designer

I have a project in visual studio (winforms, C# 4.5).  My project has ~400 projects in it.

My goal is to be able to right click on my project and, add new item (Inherited Form).

When you do so it attempts to load some number of types to pre-propulate the list for me to choose my base class from.

I get an error box (shown below), that it cannot load two different exe's.  I dont care about these two exe's.  My project doesn't reference them, and they aren't even DLL libraries, they are executables.

My goal is to be able to get vs2012 to not crap out.  Either by fixing what is wrong with these two executables, or somehow force visual studio to not care abou these two files when populating this list.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try creating a separate solution with only the projects needed to run your project. 400 projects is a massive amount and must be a nightmare to develop with.

Comment: What a lot of people don't understand about using the Visual Studio designer is that in order to get a representation of the form within the designer it is actually running portions of your code.  It's quite common to encounter exceptions in the designer that originate from code within the project.

Comment: Have you tried launching another instance of visual studio and debugging? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698388/how-to-troubleshoot-and-debug-visual-studio-design-mode-errors

... Change the Exceptions options to break on thrown....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/d14azbfh.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.  I never thought of trying to debug VS in this case.

Comment: Having similar issue except in my case it's looking for a dll of another project in the solution. However, that project is standalone and is not referenced by ANY other projects so there is zero reason it should need to have anything to do with it whatsoever. Makes no sense. I think this is a bug.