# XAML 'System.TypeInitializationException' in design mode with static property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, static

I have the following :

**File : UserControlTest.xaml**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MySolution.Views.UserControlTest"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySolution.Views"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MySolution.ViewModels"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="300"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MyViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid />
</UserControl>
```

**File : MyViewModel .cs**

```
namespace MySolution.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        try
        {
            var test = Global.Test;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.WriteLogFile(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**File : Global.cs**

```
namespace Expert.Engine
{
    public class Global
    {
        public static string Test { get; set; } = "Test Value";
    }
}
```

When i debug the XAML (attaching to process menu => XDesProc.exe relative to the above xaml file), the debugger is firing a  'System.TypeInitializationException' on Global.Test access in MyViewModel .cs :

```
try
{
    var test = Global.Test;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogHelper.WriteLogFile(ex);
}
```

Does anyone know why it does not work ? It seems that the CLR hasn't yet defined the Static class, but how make it work ?

Comment: And `Global.Test` is indeed that simple as stated in question? Also, nothing in inner exception of that TypeInitializationException?

Comment: Not sure if this works with XAML, but worth a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698388/how-to-troubleshoot-and-debug-visual-studio-design-mode-errors/13698442#13698442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.
Problem solved : 
It was finally due to a problem of Null value during the object initalization.
The designer couldn't resolve one object, so then i got an error message.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this change you code in file "Global.cs"

`public class Global` change it `public static class Global`