# C# User control with timer starts even in design mode

Tags: c#, timer

I have the following problem:

I made a user control library (DLL), which just has an enabled Timer. When I try to use this control in an application, as soon as I drag it to the Form in design mode, it starts to count! Even if the application is not running.... How can I avoid that?

My objective is that the Timer starts counting as soon as the application is launched, but not in Design Mode... because the Timer uses some external functions that cause the crash in the Design Mode.

Thank you in advanced!

Dario

Comment: Try to remove your created user control and create a new one again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.DesignMode)
       return;
    //Rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `DesignMode` property of `Control`:

```
if (!this.DesignMode) {
    // its not in design mode.. so do stuff.
}
```

Or perhaps neater:

```
yourTimer.Enabled = !this.DesignMode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `Timer` is not started in control's **constructor** - that is the most possible reason of such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you Start your Timer outside the GUI Thread and now it's ticking.
I suggest this happens in the constructor of your Control.
Change this to a separate method or post some Code to make a clear view of your Problem.

Comment: sorry copy from solution... :S

Comment: This will still start Timer in design mode

Answer (score 1):

Besides adding new `user control` from the `form`, you can also create your `user control` by coding at `Form1.Designer.cs`

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyTimer : Timer
{
    public MyTimer()
    {
        // Set your custom timer properties here.
        this.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like many people have said, you can check if the control is in design mode.

The problem you might face is that the `Control.DesignMode` property [doesn't work properly for nested controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664/designmode-with-controls/708594#708594); it always returns `false`.

Here is a fixed version that you can use instead:

```
public static bool IsDesignMode(Control control)
{
    if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)  // Initial quick check.
    {
        return true;
    }

    while (control != null)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ISite site = control.Site;

        if ((site != null) && (site.DesignMode))
            return true;

        control = control.Parent;
    }

    return false;
}
```