# Is there an equivelent of the DesignMode property for Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

In Winforms you can say (with [some slightly unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664/designmode-with-controls))

```
if (DesignMode)
{
    // Do something that only happens on Design mode
}
```

In WPF, you've got

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
    // Do something that only happens on Design mode
}
```

But I'm struggling to find a similar option for the slimmed down PCL world that is Universal apps?

Answer (score 8):

For Universal Apps, there is:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled
```